# Async jest testing with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

So I have a wrapper around my mongoose model that looks like this

```
export default class UserModel extends BaseModel {
  constructor(url) {
    super(url, "User");
    this.schema = new mongoose.Schema(userSchemaParams);
    this.name = "User";
  }

  async insert(data) {
    if (!this.connection) {
      throw new Error("No connection, please connect before using UserModel");
    }
    if (!this.model) {
      this.model = this.connection.model(this.name, this.schema);
    }
    return await this.model.create(data);
  }
}
```

When using this code I do this -

```
try {
      const userModel = new UserModel("mongodb://localhost:27017/doc_snaphunt");
      await userModel.connect();
      return await userModel.insert(dbUserData);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
```

In my jest code I have this -

```
  UserModel.prototype.insert = jest.fn();
  UserModel.prototype.connect = jest.fn();
createUser(JSON.stringify(userData));
  expect(UserModel.prototype.connect).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // TODO fix this
  expect(UserModel.prototype.insert).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The last assertion fails.

I have proven that the insert is actually called - it is failing because the assertion runs before the insert function call is called.

How do I make this work? I thought adding an `await` would solve this?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your models with their own connection? You don't appear to be understanding the core concept here. Database connections are something that are made **once** over the entire application life-cycle, and and not something that ties to model instances like this. Mongoose methods already have "internal" checks for the connection being established. You do not need to write it yourself, and you are messing up the order in the process.

Comment: Where did you define your `connect` method on the `UserModel`?

Comment: @NeilLunn AWSLambda - I'm dealing with a team that's slightly inexperienced, so for now I'm making them do it this way. I'm going to store the connection in a stored var outside of the function so that it is shared.

What will happen is the connection will get passed in to the model. 

Also these comments are totally useless to my question.

Comment: I cannot see how "working with inexperienced people" and showing them the **wrong way to do things** makes this any kind of excuse. Your problems here stem from the incorrect way you are attempting to handle the connections. If you handled them in the prescribed way instead, then you would not experience the problem.